# How to connect facebook contacts with third party app like rocket dialer, go dialer etc. in android 4.2.2?

Tags: applications, 4.2-jelly-bean, facebook, samsung-galaxy-s-4, contact-photo

I can get facebook contacts connected with the original android 4.2.2 contacts, but the connection with third party apps is not working. There seems to be some kind of updates coming with android 4.0 that has caused problems for many dialer apps...does anyone got any solution for this? The original contact app and dialer in my new samsung Galaxy S4 are not what I want...but the problems lies now with the contact photos which are not visible in the apps I'm using.